# How to set up an if statement that's checking the user's input

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

I'm trying to set my script up to read the user input, but if the input doesn't equal an integer from 1 to 10 I want it to give an Error message. How would I set it up? Like this?

```
read userinput
if [ ${userinput} != 1..10 ]; then
     echo "Error"
else
     echo $userinput
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ranges can't be used in `test`. Just test if it's out of the range with `-lt` and `-gt`

```
if [ "$userinput" -lt 1 ] || [ "$userinput" -gt 10 ]; then
```

Comment: You see, I'm also trying to make sure the user ONLY inputs an integer from 1 to 10. So for example, I want it to also give an error message if he types in characters instead of integers. How would that work?

Comment: Do that as a separate test first.